# Grid que se miniaturiza en ancho y alto proporcionalmente

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

EStoy intentando hacer esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que quiero es que se haga mas pequeño en alto y ancho cuando la pantalla se haga mas pequeña.
No tengo idea de como hacer

```
<section class="grid-blog-image">
<div class="small">
    <img src="../../../public/img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg" alt="" class="img1">
    <img src="../../../public/img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg" alt="" class="img2">
</div>
<div class="big">
    <img src="../../../public/img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="large">
    <img src="../../../public/img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg" alt="" class="img1">
    <img src="../../../public/img/carousel/moutains_home.jpg" alt="" class="img2">
</div>
```

```
.grid-blog-image {
max-width: 1000px;
height: 320px;
display: flex;
}

.grid-blog-image .small {
width: 20%;
display: inline-block;
object-fit: cover;
}

.small img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
object-fit: cover;
}

.small .img1 {
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.small .img2 {
padding-top: 3px;
}

.grid-blog-image .big {
width: 40%;
display: inline-block;
object-fit: cover;
padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
}

.big img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
object-fit: cover;
}

.grid-blog-image .large {
width: 40%;
display: inline-block;
object-fit: cover;
}

.large img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
object-fit: cover;
}

.large .img1 {
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.large .img2 {
padding-top: 3px;
}
```

El problema es que cuando la pantalla se hace pequeña se deforma, y no quiero que eso suceda, quiero que todo se mantenga proporcional, que la forma del grid sea igual pero sin deformarse, osea que no pase esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que todo cambie de tamaño proporcionalmente...

Comment: Intenta añadir media queries, para controlar el aspecto en diferentes dispositivos. Saludos.

Comment: Los `media query` no funcionan para todos los casos. En este, en especifico, necesito que siempre mantenga las proporciones, usando `media querys` solo controlaria en ciertos tamaños especificos de pantalla, si esta se hace un poco mas pequeña inmediatamente perderian la proporcion.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, encontre la solucion, es un atributo que quizas no muchos conozcan, hasta hoy yo no lo hacia, es `aspect-ratio`
Con esto puedes decidir que aspecto debería tener una imagen o Div cuando la pantalla se deforma... En mi caso, poner que tenga `proporcion 1/1` o bien, la proporcion del alto respecto al ancho

```css
.grid-blog-image {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 320px;
    display: flex;
}

.grid-blog-image .small {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.small img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.small .img1 {
    padding: 3px;
}

.small .img2 {
    padding: 3px;
}

.grid-blog-image .big {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 3px;
}

.big img {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 320/320;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.grid-blog-image .large {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.large img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 320/160;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* background: red; */
}

.large .img1 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
}

.large .img2 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-blog-image">
    <div class="small">
        <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/538/827/original/pixel-jeff-clipa-s.gif?1582740711" alt="" class="img1">
        <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/538/827/original/pixel-jeff-clipa-s.gif?1582740711" alt="" class="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="big">
        <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/538/827/original/pixel-jeff-clipa-s.gif?1582740711" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="large">
        <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/538/827/original/pixel-jeff-clipa-s.gif?1582740711" alt="" class="img1">
        <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/538/827/original/pixel-jeff-clipa-s.gif?1582740711" alt="" class="img2">
    </div>
</section>
```

Queda asi en pantalla completa de pc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi cuando es movil, todo se mantiene proporcionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, por algun motivo el cuadro grande no aplica los paddings que le agregué, pero en mi pagina si funciona bien, no se a que se deba que aqui no los muestra...